# SQL - Usuario con acceso solo a una tabla concreta de un schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

buenas soy nuevo en sql_server tengo un schema llamado Datos y dos tablas adentro del schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Datos.ciudad (nomb_ciudad VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
departamento VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE Datos.cliente (id_cliente INT PRIMARY KEY,
nomb_cliente VARCHAR(50),
direccion VARCHAR(50),
telefono INT,
tipo_cliente VARCHAR(50))

-- Cliente
create user Usuario_Clientes for login clientes with default_schema=Datos
```

quiero darle permiso de select, insert, delete, Update solo para la tabla cliente, a un usuario llamado Usuario_Clientes cual seria la forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

siguiendo la siguiente sintaxis:

```
GRANT <permission> [ ,...n ] ON   
    [ OBJECT :: ][ schema_name ]. object_name [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]  
    TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ]   
    [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]  
    [ AS <database_principal> ]
```

coloque el siguiente codigo:

```
grant select,insert,delete,Update on object::Datos.cliente to Usuario_Clientes
```

Comment: Ese object es necesario?????